# Extremely slow Excel ODBC Connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I built a dashboard in Excel that is connected to an SQL Server. There are about 20 queries made with microsoft query, using SQL parameters to extract the least possible data. Queries are extracting between 30 lines of data up to 4,000 for only one query.

The dashboard used to be very fast. The updates were running in 2-3 seconds max for all queries. Now there is inconsistency and it can take up to 5 minutes to update the same amount of data with about the same queries. There were some minor changes to some queries, but reversing the changes does not get the workbook back to its normal speed. Even deleting all the queries except one still left the workbook extremely slow. Recreating it from scratch is not an option.

I realized that the workbook is fast if I open a connection with microsoft query in a new workbook. It looks like Microsoft Query has to be opened and connected to the database on a an Excel workbook opening to have a decent speed. This trick did not work each time.

What can I do to get the speed back to normal considering that each sql query is executing in less than a quarter of second in SQL Management Studio?

I have Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

I searched on web without finding any start of a solution.

Comment: Record the run-time for each query in VBA and each worksheet update.  The problem could be in worksheet update as the data grows.

Comment: Is there any way to combine these queries on SQL side and just call the one procedure to EXCEL? EXCEL shouldn't be replacing your SSMS, anyways.

Comment: You need to work out which piece is taking the time: 1. Connecting to SQL Server, 2. Running the queries on the SQL side; 3. Rendering the data into Excel. It might be 2 that is the issue. You need to run the queries directly in a tool like SQL Server Management Studio and see how it takes

Comment: You don't provide any details about exactly how you're running your queries.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help.

Jules - I monitored the run time and it doesn't seem to be the problem as the workbook can be very fast sometimes.  The workbook is sometimes fast if I create a new blank workbook while the dashboard is open and that I create a new query with microsoft query. The workbook will be fast half of the times if after seeing the connection statement from Microsoft query.

Clifton - I guess that would be a lot of work (if possible). That's not very an option for the moment as the problem is inconsistent.

Comment: Nick - I ran a profiler and it looks like establishing connection is a problem. Each query is lightning fast in SQL Server Management Studio. Here's an excerpt of the trace:

XML: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bybw6zYPDY55Q0ktVGJiTXdlTXM
Trc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bybw6zYPDY55WFdCMXJlaWsweTQ/view?usp=sharing

I'm not sure how to read it correctly but it looks like there is problem with audit logout (the time the connection is open?) I think that the queries run fast but the connection is open for a greater amount of time.

Comment: Tim - I am running all queries with ODBC (last driver installed) and SQL Statements. Some queries have up to 3 variables parameters. I run the queries either by "Refresh All" or VBA, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found the answer after days of research.

It has nothing to do with the queries themselves. It is all about the connection string to the server and named pipes.

Place **np:** before server name such as SERVER=np:3DSERVER\3DEXPRESS

An enormous thanks to 3deers: http://www.3deers.com/blog/sql-connections-slow-windows-8-excel/.

Comment: This was a big help.  It was taking about 15 seconds to make the connection and now it is near instantaneous.